# Python C API, change python file and call modified method

Tags: c++, python-c-api

I have an application with python files next to it, from which methods will be called. And ideally the file changes should be tracked and if the file changes, it is loaded and the changed methods are called.
For example, python code download:

```
    auto p_name = PyUnicode_FromString(_python_file_name.c_str());
    if (!p_name) {
        ...
    }
    auto module = PyImport_Import(p_name);
    if (!module) {
        ...
    }
    _dict = PyModule_GetDict(module);
    if (!_dict) {
        ...
```

and code function call

```
    tryUpdateFile();  //checks when the file was changed, and if necessary, uploads a new one
    auto p_func = PyDict_GetItemString(_dict, "createPacket");
    if (!p_func || !PyCallable_Check(p_func)) {
        ...
    }
    p_return = PyObject_CallFunction(p_func, "i", id);
    auto res = parseStringFromPython(p_return);   //parse return to string
    Py_XDECREF(p_return);
    return res;
```

I expected that after changing the module PyObject_CallFunction would call the new function, but the old one is called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Importing does not re-import a module when its source has changed. See [`PyImport_ReloadModule`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module is cached in the `sys.modules` dictionary. When you load a module using `PyImport_Import`, it gets cached, and when you try to import the module again without clearing it from this cache Python will just re-use the already loaded module from the cache rather than reloading the file from disk.

You should use the `PyImport_ReloadModule()` function to reload the module once you detect that the file has changed.

This answer here should help you out: [Refreshing a import in C embedded python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543648/refreshing-a-import-in-c-embedded-python)